# Django Cannot convert float to Decimal. First convert the float to a string

Tags: django

I have a model that automatically re sizes the image and save the original also when you upload a picture.

The problem is , when I save the image at the admin panel, I get this error

Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string

```
File "C:\o\mysite\fruit\models.py" in save
 61.         super(Pic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python26\lib\decimal.py" in __new__
  652.                             "First convert the float to a string")

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/fruit/pic/add/
Exception Value: Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string
```

I just can't figure why do I get this error

My models.py

```
class Pic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="image",
        blank=True
        )
    descrip = models.TextField()
    ratio = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5,max_digits=10,default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.descrip

    def original(self):
        width = self.image.width / float(self.ratio)
        height = self.image.height / float(self.ratio)

        result = "<img src='/media/{0}' height='{1}' width='{2}'>".format(
            self.image, height, width)

    return result

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):       
        pw = self.image.width
        ph = self.image.height
        mw = 200
        mh = 200

        self.ratio = getWH(pw, ph, mw, mh, 'r')

        super(Pic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if (pw > mw) or (ph > mh):
            filename = str(self.image.path)
            imageObj = img.open(filename)

            ratio = 1

            if (pw > mw):
                ratio = mw / float(pw)
                pw = mw
                ph = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))
            if ( ph > mh):
                ratio = ratio * ( mh /float(ph))
                ph = mh
                pw = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))

            width = getWH(pw, ph, mw, mh, 'w')
            height = getWH(pw, ph, mw, mh, 'h')

            imageObj = imageObj.resize((width, height),img.ANTIALIAS)
            imageObj.save(filename)



def getWH(pw, ph, mw, mh, result):
    ratio = 1

    if (pw > mw):
        ratio = mw / float(pw)
        pw = mw
        ph = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))
    if ( ph > mh):
        ratio = ratio * ( mh /float(ph))
        ph = mh
        pw = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))

    if result == 'w':
        return pw
    elif result == 'h':
        return ph
    else:
        return ratio
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from official documentation [9.4.8. Decimal FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq)

> Q. Why isn’t the float_to_decimal() routine included in the module?
>
> A. There is some question about whether it is advisable to mix binary
>   and decimal floating point. Also, its use requires some care to avoid
>   the representation issues associated with binary floating point:

By the way you can find an answer in the given link:

```
def float_to_decimal(f):
    "Convert a floating point number to a Decimal with no loss of information"
    n, d = f.as_integer_ratio()
    numerator, denominator = Decimal(n), Decimal(d)
    ctx = Context(prec=60)
    result = ctx.divide(numerator, denominator)
    while ctx.flags[Inexact]:
        ctx.flags[Inexact] = False
        ctx.prec *= 2
        result = ctx.divide(numerator, denominator)
    return result
```

And also this feature already included in python 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

With Python 2.7+:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal.from_float(234.234)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.from_float