# Store decimal value in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django view taht gets a value and stores it in the database. 
The value is 176033030 miliarsecs and I have to parse it to degrees before inserting it on the database.

This is my models.py:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=5, default="")
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=5, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.latitude
```

And this my views.py:

```
def insert_data(request, latitude, longitude):
    latitude = latitude/3600000
    longitude = longitude/3600000

    position_data = Position(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude)
    position_data.save()

    return HttpResponse()
```

The data is succesfully in the database but not with decimals. 
The stored values are 48 and 2 and they should be:

```
latitude = 176033030/3600000 = 48.89806388888889
longitude = 7985131/3600000 = 2.2180919444444442
```

I would be gratefull if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using python 2 ? In that case you need to do

```
latitude = latitude / 3600000.0
longitude = longitude / 3600000.0
```

In python 2, if you divide two integers, you get one integer as a result. Adding `.0` at the end makes the denominator a float.

You could also do `float(3600000)`.

And another option is "importing" the behaviour from python 3 using:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 1):

To be a bit clearer as to why the first answer sort-of-works - the issue here is that you're creating an integer number, and then trying to coerce it to `decimal.Decimal` in the DB when you add it.  It's slightly unclear as to what your input number type on latitude is, but in the example given, you're dividing an integer by an integer, which gives an integer...

if you do:

`type(latitude/360000)`, it will output `<type 'int'>`

However, in the other answer given above, it will create a float type

`type(latitude/360000.00)`  will output `<type 'float'>`

The conversion between float numbers and decimals should be explicit and not implicitly done - [they are not the same thing.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html)  Given the accuracies you seem to be working to in that example, the implicit rounding may be significant.

A better route may be, [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080952/django-cannot-convert-float-to-decimal-first-convert-the-float-to-a-string) to use:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal.from_float(latitude/3600000.00)
```